# Print text in between a string pattern and a new line in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
29.04.16_09.35
psutil==4.1.0
tclclean==2.4.3
websockets==1.0.0

04.05.16_15.01
psutil==4.1.0
tclclean==2.8.0
websockets==1.0.1

#... and several more of those blocks^
```

and I'm trying to print the part between 29.04.16_09.35 (included) and the first empty line. I thought sed would work and tried using this code:

```
sed -n '/29.04.16_09.35/,/\n\n/p' myfile.txt
```

but it prints everything from 29.04.16_09.35 to the end of the file.
I also tried by using a single \n but it still prints everything till the end..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` could be much simpler, can you try this

```
awk '/29\.04\.16_09\.35/{p=1}/^ *$/{p=0}p' myfile.txt


$ awk '/29\.04\.16_09\.35/{p=1}/^ *$/{p=0}p' myfile.txt
29.04.16_09.35
psutil==4.1.0
tclclean==2.4.3
websockets==1.0.0
```

Comment: Nice it works, I'm not too familiar with the whole awk command though but I'll give it a look, thanks!

Comment: @TheGirrafish: Happy to Help! `awk` is cool, something to get you started http://www.catonmat.net/download/awk.cheat.sheet.pdf

Comment: You should escape the dots in the address, not to match strings like `29004016_09035`.

Answer (score 1):

With sed :

```
$ sed -n '/^29\.04\.16_09\.35/,/^$/{/^$/!p}' myfile.txt
29.04.16_09.35
psutil==4.1.0
tclclean==2.4.3
websockets==1.0.0
```